# CreateWindow - window is not shown in IE

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com, bho

I have this BHO in C++ that I'm writing,

Basically what I'm trying to do is open a window, but it is not shown, I think it might have something to do with the HINSTANCE I passed to it. This is the code I use, anyone recognizing what's not right in this snippet?
Thanks :)

```
IServiceProvider* pServiceProvider = NULL;
if (SUCCEEDED(m_pWebBrowser->QueryInterface(
                    IID_IServiceProvider, 
                    (void**)&pServiceProvider)))
{
    IOleWindow* pWindow = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(pServiceProvider->QueryService(
                    SID_SShellBrowser, 
                    IID_IOleWindow,
                    (void**)&pWindow)))
    {
        HWND hwndBrowser = NULL;
        if (SUCCEEDED(pWindow->GetWindow(&hwndBrowser)))
        {
HWND g_hwndMain;


g_hwndMain =  CreateWindow(TEXT ("AnxJTest Class"),TEXT("My Window"),WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE,0, 0, 200, 300,NULL, NULL, (HINSTANCE)hwndBrowser, NULL);
ShowWindow(g_hwndMain, SW_SHOW);
        }

        pWindow->Release();
    }

    pServiceProvider->Release();
}
```

Comment: Error checking? Does `CreateWindow` actually succeed? If not, have you registered the class?

Comment: Why are you casting an `HWND` to an `HINSTANCE`? What made you believe this had any chance of working whatsoever? You should pass a value that was originally passed to `RegisterClass` in `WNDCLASS::hInstance`, which is often just `NULL`.

Comment: Hi Igor, I didn't think this would work but as I asked in: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/f198bcbb-4994-417f-8543-b88008959fef/createwindow-in-ie-how-to-get-hinstance-of-parent-browser#04c3f225-e8e5-424a-8958-f7d3b4b69232 I have no idea how else I should use this handle to create the window. I tried passing null to instead but the window is not shown.

Comment: Why do you feel you "should use this handle"? What is the supposed purpose of the same? For that matter, what do you think you need "HINSTANCE of parent browser" for? If you want to have the browser window as your parent, then the parent window handle goes into the 8th parameter, not 10th. You know, the one whose type is `HWND` and whose name the documentation shows as `hWndParent`.